# Combine several string into one string in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have variable A containing several string array as follows :

```
'0'    '->'    '2'      '1.000000'    '1.000200'    'A-MPDU'     '1.000000'
'0'    'NO'    'NaN'    '1.000270'    '1.000570'    'BACKOFF'    'NaN'
```

I want to make those strings into one string form like this :

```
'0 -> 2 1.000000 1.000200 A-MPDU 1.000000'
'0 NO NaN 1.000270 1.000570 BACKOFF NaN'
```

How to realize this using matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably `A` is a cell array, so you could convert one row of it to an array of characters with

```
char(cellfun(@(x)[x ' ']',C(1,:),'UniformOutput',false))'
```

Note that we use `cellfun` to apply our anonymous function to each character array (element) of the cell array.  The function appends a space to the character array (i.e. '0' becomes '0 '), and then we transpose this result to get a column.  We do this for each element so that the final result is a column of characters which we do one final transpose on to get the string.

For example

```
>> char(cellfun(@(x)[x ' ']',C(1,:),'UniformOutput',false))'

   ans =
         0 -> 2 1.000000 1.000200 A-MPDU 1.000000 

>> char(cellfun(@(x)[x ' ']',C(2,:),'UniformOutput',false))'

   ans =
         0 NO NaN 1.000270 1.000570 BACKOFF NaN
```

Try the above and see what happens!

Comment: Is it possible to process those 2 rows at the same times using that command? Because later I will process many rows

Comment: If you try to do it all at once, then you just get one string (which you could break down in to multiple ones).

Answer (score 5):

Method 1:

If you want to combine two strings together,use [strcat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html)

```
Example:

str = strcat('Good', 'morning')

str =

Goodmorning
```

But you need spaces in between strings:

So you have to change your strings to something like: `'0 '    '-> '    '2 '`  to get the string that you want.

Another method:

```
a='aaaa';
b='bb';
c=sprintf('%s %s',a,b);
```

Comment: But in my variable I don't have ',' so when I use strcat, there is no different result

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a cell array A which has all these strings. If so, then following should work.

```
A={'0'    '->'    '2'      '1.000000'    '1.000200'    'A-MPDU'     '1.000000';
   '0'    'NO'    'NaN'    '1.000270'    '1.000570'    'BACKOFF'    'NaN'}

concatenatedCell= {[A{1,:}];[A{2,:}]}
```

Output:

```
'0->21.0000001.000200A-MPDU1.000000'
'0NONaN1.0002701.000570BACKOFFNaN'
```

You will see that the spaces are missing here (compared to your output). They will not come in your output unless: 1. they are in your input string or 2. you insert it in the string while concatenating (slightly difficult).